# Getting empty json data

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular6

I'm trying to get json data from the url, but i'm not able to get any. 
   It is just showing an empty array. What do you think that I'm missing 
   here?

**service.ts**

this is the service.ts. Im trying to get data from 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import{UserCreation} from '../../models/user-creation.model';
import{Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import{of} from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import{catchError,map,tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import{HttpClient,HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions={
    headers:new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'})
};

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})

export class UserCreationService{

//Create constructor to get Http instance
constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

private usersUrl:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

getUsers():Observable<UserCreation[]>{

return this.http.get<UserCreation[]>(this.usersUrl).pipe(
tap(receivedUsers 
=>console.log(`receivedUsers=${JSON.stringify(receivedUsers)}`)),
catchError(error=>of([]))
);
}
```

**app.component.ts**

this is the component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { UserCreationService } from '../../common/services/user- 
creation.service';


@Component({
selector: 'app',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app-component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

allUsers: UserCreation[];

constructor(private userService: UserCreationService) { }

getUsersFromServices():void{
this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
  (Users)=>{
    this.allUsers=Users;
    console.log(`this.allUsers = ${JSON.stringify(this.allUsers)}`);

  }
 )
}

ngOnInit(): void {
this.getUsersFromServices();
}
```

Comment: Is that API even getting called? I think `private usersUrl:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';` should contain `=` sign instead of `:` like this - `private usersUrl='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';`

Comment: does `console.log(`receivedUsers=${JSON.stringify(receivedUsers)}`)),` print anything

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri well caught, you should make that an answer

Answer (score 2):

There is typo error here - `private usersUrl:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';`.

It should be `=` instead of `:` like this - `private usersUrl='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';`.

Or better way `private usersUrl:string = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';`